# Is this question off topic, if so why?

Tags: discussion

> What is the sentiment of Chinese exchanges with respect to accepting Ethereum? [on hold]
>
> up vote
>   -2
>   down vote
>   favorite
>   With the recent successful news of Ethereum adoption, are the Chinese exchanges taking note and considering accepting Ethereum?

I've updated to make it more answerable.

> Are there any measurable indicators of Chinese exchanges accepting Ethereum? [on hold]
>
> up vote
>   -2
>   down vote
>   favorite
>
> With the recent successful news of Ethereum adoption, are the Chinese exchanges taking note and considering accepting Ethereum? Are there any specific metrics indicating the adoption of Ethereum in China?

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 2):

I think a consensus on what's on or off topic hasn't been reached yet. I would say that the subject (Chinese exchanges) is on topic, but the question is hard to answer with a specific answer. Sentiment is hard to judge; sentiment of a number of exchanges, which represents even more people, and will change over time doesn't make a good thing to judge on this site.

Comment: How's the new edit?